# Will Cramer Rao Lower Bound converge to the variance of MLE in the below probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

The pdf is given such as, 
 
$f(x;\theta) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\theta\pi x^3}}e^{\frac{-(x-1)^2}{2\theta x}})$

Is it necessary that in this case, the Maximum Likelihood Estimator will be equal to the CRLB in this case?